# Conquest Commander: Is there a cruise missle on every map?

Tags: battlefield-4

I started playing commander last night, and I had access to a cruise missile on Flood Zone, but the entire game of Rogue Transmission I never had cruise missile access.

Do all maps include a cruise missile?  If so, for each of the maps, which point grants cruise missile access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not all maps include cruise missiles** and the capture point required for cruise missile is usually the one in the middle of the map (often C). The maps that have cruise missiles usually have a large body of water bordering the map (for example Siege of Shanghai, Flood Zone and Hainan Resort). On maps where the cruise missile is unavailable, it is often (if not always) replaced with a gunship instead.

Added: You can see what commander assets are assigned to a point by highlighting the flag with your crosshair when not playing as commander. The little icon (if there is one) displays what commander assets is attributed to that point.